# php is being downloaded instead of being loaded

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I got a nginx docker container which actually works. Because when i do `curl localhost:7070` on my host i get the content of the site as return. Then  i made a config for nginx on my host, the problem is when i try to open the site in a browser it downloads the php file. I will sahre both configs of host nginx and docker nginx.

Nginx host conf:

```
    server {
            #listen 80 default_server;
            #listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
            # SSL configuration
           
             listen 7171 ssl default_server;
             listen [::]:7171 ssl default_server;    
            root /var/www/html;
    
            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
            server_name SERVERNAME;
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7070;
                #proxy_redirect     off;
                #proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                #proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
}
```

nginx docker conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/selfoss;

    index index.php index.html;

    location ~* \ (gif|jpg|png) {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ ^/(favicons|thumbnails)/.*$ {
        try_files $uri /data/$uri;
    }

    location ~* ^/(data\/logs|data\/sqlite|config\.ini|\.ht) {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri /public/$uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

I know alittle about nginx normal config but im noob at php so what is the thing that im missing here?

I have seen posts about php-fpm and fastcgi but i have no clue ho or where to do that  config changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a configured PHP-FPM in your Nginx-Config and of course a running PHP-FPM (inside the same Docker-Container or in a separate Docker-Container).

Example Nginx-Config inside your `server{}` section

```
location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/sockets/php/www.sock;
    }
```

Comment: hi, do i need to do that for both configs or only host or docker?

Comment: Only for your _docker_ config. As I see the _host_ config is just a reverse proxy to your Nginx in Docker.

Comment: Getting bad gateway 502 now :S

Comment: the blogpost i used for the install used trhis in his config

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

but i dont have snippets and the php cgi conf